# Warn the user before session timeout

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, session

I have a web application implemented in `Spring MVC`, `JSP`.
Default session timeout is defined in `web.xml` is 30 min.

if user is idle for 25 mins  than I need to show a popup to user with message that `Your session is going to be end by 5 min, Please click OK to continue`.

Do we can achieve this using `JavaScript`, `jquery` or any other approach?

Please suggest.

Comment: you can use websockets

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti how to use websockets? I couldn't find any example

Answer (score 4):

Try this code. Hopefully it will solve your problem. Thanks

```
var cookieName = 'sessionMsg';
var message = 'Your session is going to be end by 5 min, Please click OK to continue';

function getCookie(name)
{
    var name = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function setSessionPrompt() {
    var timeout = getCookie(cookieName) - new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (new Date().getTime() < getCookie(cookieName)) {
            setSessionPrompt();
        } else {
            if(confirm(message)) {
                // do your action here
            }
        }
    }, timeout);
}

setSessionPrompt();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use like follows: I am using that in a jsp page like header.jsp. It works fine for me. I am using spring, jsp and jquery.

javascript:

```
<code>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //var recall = true;
    function loadDialog() { 
            var sessionAlive = ${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval};          
            var notifyBefore = 30; // Give client 15 seconds to choose.
            setTimeout(function() {       
                $(function() {
                    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        maxWidth:400,
                        maxHeight: 200,
                        width: 400,
                        height: 200,
                        modal: true,
                        open: function(event, ui) {
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('#dialog').dialog('close'); 
                            }, notifyBefore * 1000);
                        },
                        buttons: {
                        "Yes": function() {  
                             $.get("/about", function(data,status){
                               // alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                              });                             
                            $('#dialog').dialog("close");
                            loadDialog();
                        },
                        "No": function() {  
                            $('#dialog').dialog("close");
                        }
                       },
                       close: function() {}
                    });
                  });
            }, (sessionAlive - notifyBefore) * 1000);
    };

    loadDialog(); 
</script>
```

HTML Div:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Session Timeout Info" style="display:none">
  <p>
    Your session will be timeout within 30 seconds. Do you want to continue session?  
  </p>
</div> 
</code>
```

Comment: This gives this error: `TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function`

Answer (score 2):

You could send a cookie with the remaining time (in milliseconds) on every request. Then you can use setTimeout as suggested but test the value again when the timeout-function is executed. If the value has changed you can reset the timeout. Since the cookie is set for the whole domain it will always be correct even for ajax or other tabs.

```
var cookieName = 'sessionMsg';
var message = 'Your session is going to be end by 5 min, Please click OK to continue';

function getCookie(name)
{
    var name = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function setSessionPrompt() {
    var timeout = getCookie(cookieName) - new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (new Date().getTime() < getCookie(cookieName)) {
            setSessionPrompt();
        } else {
            if(confirm(message)) {
                // do your action here
            }
        }
    }, timeout);
}

setSessionPrompt();
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to notify the user about the timeouts on the frontend, you need to pass this information from your backend. To accomplish this, I used the info in https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073234/tracking-session-expiration-in-browser.html as a baseline.

In each Response method in your Controller you need to include cookies containing the session timeout time, as well as the current server time. Since it sounds like you've already set the session-timeout in your web.xml, you can add the cookies to your response with something similar to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/example", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> getExample(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
     addTimeoutCookies(servletRequest, servletResponse);

     //Do actual actions

     return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.OK)
}

private void addTimeoutCookies(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {

    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long expiryTime = currTime + servletRequest.getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000;

    Cookie serverTimeCookie = new Cookie("serverTime", "" + currTime);
    serverTimeCookie.setPath("/");
    servletResponse.addCookie(serverTimeCookie);

    Cookie expiryCookie = new Cookie("sessionExpiry", "" + expiryTime);
    expiryCookie.setPath("/");
    servletResponse.addCookie(expiryCookie);
}
```

Then, on the frontend, you need to retrieve the values of these cookies and compare them against the client current time to determine when to notify the user about the upcoming session timeout. Here's a simple code block to do this, based on the other answers here and the article at the link:

```
var currTimeCookieName = 'serverTime';
var expireTimeCookieName = 'sessionExpiry';
var offset;
var warningTime = 5 * 60 * 1000;
var timeoutWarningMessage = 'Your session is going to be end by 5 min, Please click OK to continue';

function getCookie(name)
{
    var name = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

var serverTime = getCookie(currTimeCookieName);
serverTime = serverTime==null ? null : Math.abs(serverTime);
var offset = (new Date()).getTime() - serverTime;

function getTimeToWarning() {
    var expireTime = getCookie(expireTimeCookieName);
    return expireTime + offset - currTime - warningTime;
}

function checkForTimeout() {
    var timeUntilWarning = getTimeToWarning();

    setTimeout(function(){
        if (getTimeToWarning() > 0) {
            checkForTimeout();
        } else {

            if(confirm(timeoutWarningMessage)) {
                //TODO do a backend call or other action to extend the session here

                setTimeout(function() {
                    checkForTimeout();
                }, 1 * 60 * 1000);
            }
        }
    }, timeUntilWarning);
}

checkForTimeout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know
windows.setTimeout

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

This is what you need

For example

```
var resetTime_int;
function resetTimer(){
    if(resetTime_int) window.clearTimeout(resetTime_int)
    resetTime_int=window.setTimeout(function (){
    if(prompt('Your session is going to be end by 5 min, Please click OK to continue'))     
    location.reload()
    }, 1000*60*25)
}

resetTimer()
document.onmousemove=resetTimer
document.onkeyup=resetTimer
```

1000*60*25 = 25 Minutes.

Comment: He needs a server-side approach. The user is only logged out if *idle* for 30 minutes. This will warn the user ignoring that fact.

Comment: Let's say the user logins in at 12:00. They interact with the web app until 12:05. The user should be logged out at 12:35, thereby being warned at 12:30. With your approach, they will be warned at 12:25.

Comment: If the user interact with the web app, the server will not know about it. If the user doing some ajax, you need to reset the timer.

Comment: Most of the time, the server will know about it unless everything is completely client-side without any AJAX.

Comment: Yes Sam..you are right. I need the inactive interval time of the user. If it reaches 25 min than only i need to show the message. With the approach Amina it will show the message after 25 min of login. Please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: Still not working; resetTimer should send some kind of do-nothing AJAX request to the server to reset the server-side session timeout too. Once that is addressed, I think that this approach is better than web-sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You should use WebSockets to send data from the Web Application to clients browser.

1) calculate the session timeouts at server side.
2) Websocket will send the message about session time out message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following plugin - [Jtimeout jquery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Session-Timeout-Warning-jTimeout.html)
Works perfectly and is configurable too. The doc is pretty clear

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation in your answer. Answers are strongly encouraged to have their solution be entirely in the post itself. That means including more than just a link to some external resource. If the link you included breaks, your answer will become worse than useless. Maybe write a small example that uses the plugin you've linked, or at least highlight the specific plugin methods you think would solve the asker's problem.