# Warn user before session time out in spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, spring, model-view-controller

I have a web application implemented in Spring MVC, JSP having default timeout is 30 minutes.

I need to show alert in UI saying "Your session is going to end in 5 minutes. Please click OK to continue" if the session is going to expire in another 5 minutes.

How to achieve this in better way?

I found few answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930541/warn-the-user-before-session-timeout)

Just interested to know if there is any other better way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question. Currently it could be considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

try this out,below code works me fine

```
var cookieName = 'sessionMsg';
var message = 'Your session is Expires 5 min, click OK to continue';

function getCookie(name)
{
    var name = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function setSessionPrompt() {
    var timeout = getCookie(cookieName) - new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (new Date().getTime() < getCookie(cookieName)) {
            setSessionPrompt();
        } else {
            if(confirm(message)) {
                // do your action here
            }
        }
    }, timeout);
}

setSessionPrompt();
```

Comment: HI,thanks for the rly but this code  is not working correctly ,               when ever i reload the page, pop box is displayed, not when session is expired ,Suggest some other solution please