# How to display a warning message to the user for an impending session timeout in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warnings, session-timeout

I would like to display a timeout warning to the user (some kind of countdown say 2 mins before session timeout)

I am not sure how to display a warning `before` timeout

I currently use this code in `ApplicationController` class to check if the user is logged in/valid each time the controller is hit:

```
def check_login
  logger.info "ApplicationController check_login"

  if session[:current_user]
    <do something>
  else
    redirect_to login_path, flash: {notice: 'We require you to sign in.'}
  end
end
```

But I don't know how to display a warning 2 mins `before` session timeout. Please help!

Comment: Your session will only timeout if the user is not doing anything. So actively checking/asking using an API to check if the session is timing out, will keep it active. You will have to add some javascript code on each page, to warn the user if that page is inactive for `@timeout - 5.minutes` to warn the user. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930541/warn-the-user-before-session-timeout

Answer (score 1):

> you can use before_action filter in application_controller.rb like

```
Class ApplicationController
  before_action :check_session_has_expired

  def check_session_has_expired
     if !session[:user].present?
        redirect_to :session_warning_url
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My requirement is this - say the session timeout is 5 min. I would like to display a warning to the user 2 min before timeout saying "2 min left to timeout". How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

ok you can also set expire_at in session

```
session[:expire_at] = Time.current + 24.hours
```

Then, Make ajax request to server after every two minutes

and check condition below

```
if Time.current - session[:expires_at] < 2.minutes
  # show warning
end
```

Comment: function sessionCheck() {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
      url: '/security/ping'
  })
  .done(function(j) {
    if (j['res'] != 'ok') {
    } else {
      startSessionPing();
    }
  })
  .fail(function() {
    document.location = "/security/login";
  });
}

Comment: Thanks for the reply again! May I ask where should I place `session[:expire_at] = Time.current + 24.hours` and `if Time.current - session[:expires_at] < 2.minutes
  # show warning
end` ?

Comment: Especially the check `if Time.current - session[:expires_at] < 2.minutes
  # show warning
end` Ideally this check should be happening every second. If I place it in the controller in a method `timeout_warning` and include that method in `before_action`, then `timeout_warning` would be called everytime the controller is hit. How do I make sure `timeout_warning` is called every second?

Comment: where you are creating sessions  or when user signin

Comment: not every second you can run after every 15 seconds