# Java spring security event before session expires

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Java 8 + spring 5. what i am trying to do use find out 10 seconds in advance which session is going to expire.

i found the following code snippet which helps to identify which session is expire but how do i find out this 10 seconds before ?

```
@Component
public class LogoutListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event)
    {
        List<SecurityContext> lstSecurityContext = event.getSecurityContexts();
        UserDetails ud;
        for (SecurityContext securityContext : lstSecurityContext)
        {
            ud = (UserDetails) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to know it 10 seconds before?

Comment: before session expires we want to let user know that session is about to expire so if they perform any action session will reset. 10 seconds is a random number it can be any thing but before session expires.

Comment: There are a few methods where you track the remaining time on the client. You could pass the remaining time in the response on each request and let the client run a timer. See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930541/warn-the-user-before-session-timeout or similar can point you in the right direction.